# Same Association Twice, Different Names, Second Uses Wrong Column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-associations

I'm trying to create two associations that are identical in nature but have two different names because they mean different things. I have a feeling that this is a syntax issue I can't quite get right. I'd rather not rewrite the base level models, but I'm open to suggestions. As far as the modeling goes: Raids have players. Raids have leaders (which are players). I want this players to raids association to exist in the players_raids table and leaders_raids table. The two sets of method calls need to be complementary: players.raids and raids.players, and players.raids_led and raids.leaders.

**player.rb:**

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players_raids, class_name: 'PlayersRaids'
  has_many :raids, through: :players_raids
  has_many :leaders_raids, class_name: 'LeadersRaids'
  has_many :raids_led, through: :leaders_raids, source: :leader, foreign_key: 'leader_id'
end
```

**raid.rb:**

```
class Raid < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players_raids, class_name: 'PlayersRaids'
  has_many :players, through: :players_raids
  has_many :leaders_raids, class_name: 'LeadersRaids'
  has_many :leaders, through: :leaders_raids
end
```

**players_raids.rb:**

```
class PlayersRaids < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :raid
end
```

**leaders_raids.rb:**

```
class LeadersRaids < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :leader, class_name: 'Player'
  belongs_to :raid
end
```

**create_players_raids.rb**

```
class CreatePlayersRaids < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :players_raids, id: false do |t|
      t.references :player
      t.references :raid
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**creates_leaders_raids.rb**

```
class CreateLeadersRaids < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :leaders_raids, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :leader_id
      t.references :raid
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**raids_controller.rb**

```
class RaidsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @raid = Raid.new(params[:raid])
    @raid.leaders << current_player
    @raid.players << current_player
    if @raid.save
      redirect_to raid_path(@raid), notice: "#{@raid.name} created!"
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

Some of these sections are areas I've been playing around with, namely the 'source' and 'foreign_key' fields on the 'raids_led' association in the Player model and the name/reference that is currently 't.integer :leader_id' in the LeadersRaids table migration file.

When a new raid is created, the current_player (my ApplicationController version of current_user as my Player model is the more common User model) should be added as both a player and a leader for the newly created raid. When I use raid.players, raid.leaders, and player.raids I get back exactly what I expect. However, when I use player.raids_led I get an error that it's trying to use raids_leaders.player_id instead of raids_leaders.leader_id (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'leaders_raids.player_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `players`.* FROM `players` INNER JOIN `leaders_raids` ON `players`.`id` = `leaders_raids`.`leader_id` WHERE `leaders_raids`.`player_id` = 1). Can anyone help me resolve where my syntax is lacking?

**EDIT:**
I updated these models and it seems to be functioning as was my original intent. Maybe it was just some sleep and a fresh perspective. Feel free to update or comment if there's a better way to do this.

**player.rb:**

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :characters
  has_many :players_raids, class_name: 'PlayersRaids'
  has_many :raids, through: :players_raids
  has_many :leaders_raids, class_name: 'LeadersRaids'
  has_many :raids_led, through: :leaders_raids, source: :raid
end
```

**raid.rb:**

```
class Raid < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players_raids, class_name: 'PlayersRaids'
  has_many :players, through: :players_raids
  has_many :leaders_raids, class_name: 'LeadersRaids'
  has_many :leaders, through: :leaders_raids, source: :leader
end
```

**leaders_raids.rb:**

```
class LeadersRaids < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :leader, class_name: 'Player', foreign_key: 'player_id'
  belongs_to :raid
end
```

**create_leaders_raids.rb:**

```
class CreateLeadersRaids < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :leaders_raids, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :player_id
      t.references :raid
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```